# Cauchy problem $pq -3xy-2u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for a solution of the following PDE problem:

$pq -3xy-2u=0$

$u = 15y$

$x = 5$

I have looked for examples where this pq to see how it solve, but I do not understand. In my class I have seen solve exercises but I had never seen one with pq. How I can start to solve this exercise, please help.

Comment: Surely there are constraints on $p$ and $q$...

Comment: $p=du/dx$ and $q=du/dy$